# Dragover - is there a drag out?

Tags: jquery

I have the following for drag over:

```
$(window).on('dragover', this.onDragOver);
```

Is there a drag out or something similar, I need to fire an event for when the user moves off the window.

Comment: Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events#Drag_events

Answer (score 27):

It sounds like you're looking for the [dragleave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/dragleave) event. From the docs:

> The `dragleave` event is fired when a dragged element or text selection leaves a valid drop target.

Comment: Thanks, but drag leave seems to fire when I enter the wind for the first time, is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3):

I would try one of these two events:

focus out
http://api.jquery.com/focusout/

or

mouse leave
http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

Answer (score 2):

There is a dragleave event, but it's more like the opposite of dragenter